# java modal frame with maximize button

Tags: java, swing, modal-dialog, frame, maximize

I wonder if it possible:

1. to make a jdialog (which can be modal) with maximize button (is it possible to make custom but which will maximize frame?)
2. or to make jframe (which has default maximize button) modal?

There lots of topic about this, but I found no clean solutions. Only tricks with setEnabled(), etc.

Thanks everyone in advance!

Comment: There is always JInternalFrame, but I don't think you can make it modal, and it is not exactly like a JFrame

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- AFAIK not possible, because Top-Level Containers came from Native OS,
- then mouse double click to the JFrame's toolbar resize container to fills whole screen Dimension, second double ćlick restore lastz known Dimension
- this not possible with JDialog
- from any of Mouse(Xxx)Listener doesn't response mouse_events from toolbar that came from Native OS, only from are that fills RootPane

code example

```
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.Timer;
//http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8670297/make-java-swing-modal-dialog-behave-like-mac-osx-dialogs
public class ModalDialogDemoFrame extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private ModalDialogDemoFrame modalDialogDemo;

    public ModalDialogDemoFrame() {
        modalDialogDemo = this;
        setBounds(100, 100, 400, 400);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JButton buttonDialog = new JButton("Open Dialog");
        buttonDialog.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                // Create a Modal Dialog with this Frame as Parent.
                ModalDialog modalDialog = new ModalDialog(modalDialogDemo, true);
                modalDialog.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        getContentPane().add(buttonDialog, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                try {
                    ModalDialogDemoFrame window = new ModalDialogDemoFrame();
                    window.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
//http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4577424/distinguish-between-a-single-click-and-a-double-click-in-java/4577475#4577475
class ClickListener extends MouseAdapter implements ActionListener {

    private final static int clickInterval = (Integer) Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getDesktopProperty("awt.multiClickInterval");
    private MouseEvent lastEvent;
    private Timer timer;

    public ClickListener() {
        this(clickInterval);
    }

    public ClickListener(int delay) {
        timer = new Timer(delay, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        if (e.getClickCount() > 2) {
            return;
        }
        lastEvent = e;
        if (timer.isRunning()) {
            timer.stop();
            doubleClick(lastEvent);
        } else {
            timer.restart();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        timer.stop();
        singleClick(lastEvent);
    }

    public void singleClick(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    public void doubleClick(MouseEvent e) {
    }
}

class ModalDialog extends JDialog {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public ModalDialog(JFrame parent, boolean modal) {
        Dimension dimensionParentFrame = parent.getSize();
        setSize(new Dimension((parent == null) ? 300 : dimensionParentFrame.width / 2, 75));
        Dimension dimensionDialog = getSize();
        int x = parent.getX() + ((dimensionParentFrame.width - dimensionDialog.width) / 2);
        setLocation(x, parent.getY() + parent.getInsets().top);
        //setUndecorated(true);
        setModal(modal);
        setModalityType(ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        JButton buttonClose = new JButton("Close");
        buttonClose.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                dispose();
            }
        });
        add(buttonClose, BorderLayout.CENTER); // comment for listening 
        addMouseListener(new ClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void singleClick(MouseEvent e) {
                System.out.println("single");
            }

            @Override
            public void doubleClick(MouseEvent e) {
                System.out.println("double");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Please have a look at this, you can use JDialog for what you are saying in your question.

[Java modal window with maximize button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3897927/java-modal-window-with-maximize-button)