# How to put maximize and minimize buttons in a jDialog?

Tags: java, swing, jdialog

my question is very simple. I am creating an app with Java swing, and i realized that the jDialogs doesn´t have maximize and minimize buttons, instead of the jFrame.

[image]

There is a way to add it to it? or if not, what can i do if i want to replace the jDialog to another swing component that it has?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I think this is already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3897927/java-modal-window-with-maximize-button). In short, it is suggested you use a JFrame instead. But it can not be modal as I understood.

Comment: Could be a solution, but i think using more than one JFrame is a bad practice. So i will avoid it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my question, i have used the cardLayout to create differents jPanels and including into my jFrame, every time that i want to show another "window" i change it to the corresponding jPanel..

You can see the documentation of cardLayout here:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html